Error with Celery+S3 celery.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Missing bucket name
This is my script to have a celery on SQS and S3 as the result backend:
from celery import Celery

from celery.backends.s3 import S3Backend


# Set your SQS queue URL
sqs_queue_url = 'https://sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/938891507445/test-sqs-queue'

app = Celery('tasks')


app.conf.update(
    broker='sqs://',
    broker_transport_options={
        'region': 'eu-central-1',
        'predefined_queues': {
            'celery': {
                'url': sqs_queue_url,
            },
        },
        'task_create_missing_queues': False,
    },
    result_backend='s3://',  # Use a string URL format for the backend
    result_backend_transport_options={
        'region_name': 'eu-central-1',
        'bucket_name': 'celery-back',
        'prefix': 'celery-results',
        'expiration': 3600,
    }
)


# Define a simple Celery task
@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


# Example usage: calling the task
if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = add.delay(4, 6)
    print(f'Task result: {result.get(timeout=10)}')

But when I try to run it using celery 5.4, like this:
poetry run celery -A cel worker --loglevel=info

And error says:
root@ip:/app# poetry run celery -A cel worker --loglevel=info
/app/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/platforms.py:829: SecurityWarning: You're running the worker with superuser privileges: this is
absolutely not recommended!

Please specify a different user using the --uid option.

User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0

  warnings.warn(SecurityWarning(ROOT_DISCOURAGED.format(
[2024-12-02 21:09:28,126: WARNING/MainProcess] No hostname was supplied. Reverting to default 'localhost'
[2024-12-02 21:09:28,145: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: ImproperlyConfigured('Missing bucket name')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 202, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 112, in start
    self.on_start()
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/apps/worker.py", line 135, in on_start
    self.emit_banner()
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/apps/worker.py", line 169, in emit_banner
    ' \n', self.startup_info(artlines=not use_image))),
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/apps/worker.py", line 231, in startup_info
    results=self.app.backend.as_uri(),
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 1303, in backend
    self._backend = self._get_backend()
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 971, in _get_backend
    return backend(app=self, url=url)
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/backends/s3.py", line 47, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('Missing bucket name')
celery.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Missing bucket name

I ran a script to put a file in S4 and send a message to SQS from the same environment, So there is not problem with the bucket name or permissions
